# Java printing an array?

Tags: java, arrays

I have an array:

```
private String[] gamesArray = new String[] {"spin", "tof"};
```

And when I start the program, I want the program to print the items in the array:

```
Please select a game: spin, tof.
```

This is my attempt:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

private Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
private Spin spin = new Spin();
private String input = "";
private String[] gamesArray = new String[] {"spin", "tof"};

public static void main (String[] args) {

    System.out.println("Welcome to the system!");

    for (String s : gamesArray) {

        System.out.println("Please select a game:" + s);

    }

}
}
```

Error:

```
src\Main.java:15: error: non-static variable gamesArray cannot be referenced fro
m a static context
                for (String s : gamesArray) {
                                ^
```

***What is wrong?***

Comment: Rather than making gamesArray a field, you could create the variable inside of your main method

Comment: On a side note, this will not print what you intend. Rather it will print:

Please select a game: spin
Please select a game: tof

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to print an instance field without an instance. The main() method is static.

You could solve this by declaring gamesArray to be a static field. For example:

```
 private static final String[] gamesArray = new String[] {"spin", "tof"};
```

Alternatively, you could make an instance of the class Main(), and accessing the field through that.

```
 Main myMain = new Main();
 for (String s : myMain.gamesArray) {
```

Once you do one of those, you'll notice the output looks like this:

```
Please select a game:spin
Please select a game:tof
```

You may want the "Please select the game" to be outside the loop.

Comment: Thanks Andy, can you please link me to a place that explains everything about the difference between a regular int, String, other methods, and Statics + void methods? I've been searching the docs, couldn't really find what I want.

Comment: @JonyKale, http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html is a good place to start.

Comment: @JonyKale - Here's another: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/797964/what-is-the-exact-meaning-of-static-fields-in-java . As an example, consider a hypothetical class Human. The species name could be a static field. An individual's height could be an instance field.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create the object of class first

```
 Main obj = new Main();
 for(String s : obj.gamesArray){
       System.out.println("Please select a game:" + s);

 }
```

- A static method or variable can be accessed directly from static method. If you declare the array as `private static String[] gamesArray = new String[] {"spin", "tof"};` then you could have accessed it without creating the object of `Main` class
- But you can access a static variable directly from an instance method because static variables are shared variables across all the instances.
- If you want to access instance variables directly, then you can access them in instance methods and not static methods.

  ```
  public class StaticNonStatic {

  private static int staticVar;
  private int instanceVar;

  public void instanceMethod(){
      System.out.println(instanceVar);// instance variable accessed directly
      System.out.println(staticVar); // static variable accessed directly from instance method
  }

  public static staticMethod(){
      System.out.println(instnaceVar); // no this is wrong, can't access instance member from static block directly
      System.out.println(instnaceVar); // fair enough, accessing static member from static method directly
  }

  }
  ```

Comment: I like that name, `obj`, since it tells me it's an object and not a giraffe or a tuna fish.

Answer (score 0):

GamesArray is an instance member of your class. Since main method is always static there is no instance of the class to get at gamesArray. Consider making gamesArray static