# what is the role of "static" keyword in java?

Tags: java

I frequently see static keyword with variables and with methods. Why we use static with main(String args[]) method in java ? Can anybody explain me the role of static in easy terms. So i can understand it better

Comment: "_Why we use static with main(String args[]) method in java_" Because the specification ask it, and because there is no instance of that class yet. "_Can anybody explain me the role of static in easy terms_" For an explanation, you should follow a course on Java to get this part, this is no complicated but this doesn't seems to fit on SO

Comment: [possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/797964/what-is-the-exact-meaning-of-static-fields-in-java)  -  [answer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_variable)

Comment: In computer programming, a static variable is a variable that has been allocated statically so that its lifetime or "extent" extends across the entire run of the program