# How does a method get called by a constant?

Tags: java

I am designing a program for converting distances between units and have been given code to test this. I don't understand how to write my method so that is can be called by a constant. The following code is given:

```
System.out.println(DistanceUnit.METER.toMetric(100));
  System.out.println(DistanceUnit.METER.fromMetric(100));
  System.out.println(DistanceUnit.FOOT.toMetric(100));
  System.out.println(DistanceUnit.FOOT.fromMetric(100));
  System.out.println(DistanceUnit.PLANCK.toMetric(100));
  System.out.println(DistanceUnit.PLANCK.fromMetric(100));;
  System.out.println(DistanceUnit.PARSEC.toMetric(100));
  System.out.println(DistanceUnit.PARSEC.fromMetric(100));
```

So I have defined the constants above according to the instructions in the assignment but how do I create the methods fromMetric and toMetric so that they can be called by the constants from DistanceUnits?

Comment: This looks like an `enum`, not constants.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Assignments aren't usually arbitrary; your instructor, tutorial, or course will have covered the necessary topics to make it possible for you to do this. **Review your course materials, class notes, etc.,** and try to do the work. *If* you run into a *specific* problem, research it thoroughly, [search thoroughly here](/help/searching), and if you're still stuck post your code and a description of the problem. People will be glad to help.

Comment: Might be enums, might just be instances of a (non-enum) class.

Comment: *(Trying to figure out what `METER.fromMetric` and `METER.toMetric` would do...)*

Comment: Yeah I get that. But the assignment clearly states that I am to create a class called DiatanceUnit and that it should contain a constructor DistanceUnit(double metersPerUnit) and the the constants PLANCK, METER, FOOT and PARSEC and have been given a table with values to use for them

Comment: I don't know if I've posed the question in a poor manner. But my issue is that I don't get how I am supposed to write a method like:
public double toMetric(double input) { 
 return "constant that called the mathod" * input;
}

Comment: Whereas I concur that `DistanceUnit` looks like an enum, more generally, you can invoke methods only on objects, so `DistanceUnit.METER` must be objects.  That is not inherently inconsistent with  Java code conventions.  (And Java enum values are objects, and they can have arbitrary methods.)

Comment: @NiklasWesterberg The thing is that your *constants* like `METER` are not supposed to be primitives, they are **not** `double`. Instead they all are objects. And objects can have methods. And probably all those objects have a member variable that defines the scale of the unit which is then used in the given method. Take a look at the answer of @tsolakp, it is a full code example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comments and the answer from @GhostCat should be all you need to implement those constants but I have feeling that you are still thinking about constants in terms of primitives/strings and not as objects. In java constants can also reference any objects.

Here is example for METER and FOOT implementation using interface and concrete implementations:

```
    public class DistanceUnit{
        public static final Converter METER = new MeterConverter();
        public static final Converter FOOT = new FootConverter();
    }


    public interface Converter{

        public double fromMetric(double d);

        public double toMetric(double d);       
    }

    public class MeterConverter implements Converter{

        @Override
        public double fromMetric(double d) {
            return d;
        }

        @Override
        public double toMetric(double d) {
            return d;
        }        
    }

    public class FootConverter implements Converter{

        @Override
        public double fromMetric(double meters) {
            return meters*3.28084;
        }

        @Override
        public double toMetric(double feet) {
            return feet*0.3048;
        }        
    }
```

There is better way to do this by replacing `DistanceUnit` with enum but I am leaving it to you as an exercise.

Comment: I was too lazy typing more code on my mobile. You got my vote for adding more details!

Comment: Thanks. I decided to add my answer when I saw @Niklas Westerberg comment to your answer.

Answer (score 3):

Keep in mind: methods exists on **classes**. Yes, you can define methods on interfaces, too - but the point is: you can **invoke** methods only on *objects*, or on classes (when they are static).

In that sense, you have to first figure the *type* of your CONSTANT. In other words: you first have to understand that "CONSTANT" simply refers to some object that has a certain name.

And from there: you already defined somehow the *type* of that object named CONSTANT. And when you want to invoke methods on objects of that type, you have to *add* them to that type.

In other words, assuming that you have something like:

```
class DistanceUnit {
  public final static Foo METER = new Foo(...);
```

you would need

```
class Foo {
  public static String fromMetric(int value);
```

for example.

And just for the record: it doesn't really matter whether DistanceUnit.METER refers to a static field within a class, or to an *enum* - your todo is the same: that *type* that METER represents needs the corresponding methods. And in case you don't understand the *difference* between these concepts, start reading [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) for enums and [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/797964/what-is-the-exact-meaning-of-static-fields-in-java) for static fields.

Comment: public static final double METER = 1;
public static final double FOOT = 0.3048; 
public static final double PARSEC = 3.08567758 * Math.pow(10, 16);
public static final double PLANCK = 1.616229 * Math.pow(10, -35);

This is my declaration of the constants in the class DistanceUnit. I might be way off here but is what you saying that the primitive type double has to have the methods?

Comment: Can you read the code you put into this comment? Really? Please enhance your question accordingly instead of providing more information in comments like this! And what I am saying is : the type of  METER must be a type to which you can add methods. Because you own that type! thus you cannot use double here. All the information you need is already written in my answer!

Comment: No, primitives like `double` don't have methods that you can call on them. However you can define classes as *constants* too, not only primitives. The term *constant* usually only refers to something being `static` and `final`.

Comment: @Zabuza - You cannot mark an object as constant in Java using the `static` and `final` qualifiers. They affect only the *reference* to an object.

Comment: @AndyThomas Yeah, of course I meant that. But thanks for clarifying if someone didn't knew.

Answer (score 0):

A single enum is sufficient. Java enum constants are objects. You can call methods on them.

Standard style is to uppercase the enum constants.

You only have to write `toMetric()` and `fromMetric()` once.

```
public enum DistanceUnit {
   METER( 1.0 ),
   FOOT( 0.3048 ),
   ...
   ;

   private m_distanceInMeters;

   DistanceUnit( double distanceInMeters ) {
     ...
   }

   public double fromMetric(double d) {
     ...
   }

   public double toMetric(double d) {
     ...
   }
}
```