# Initializing objects with static values

Tags: java, static, initialization, static-methods

Every time I create an object of the class it returns the same value every time, even if the object is different with different values. How can I make sure that this doesn't happen?

```
class Something{
  protected String name;
  protected static double price; // need the value later

  public Something(String xName, double xPrice){
    name = xName;
    price = xPrice;
  }

  public String returnName(){
    return name;
  }

  public static returnPrice(){
    return price;
  }
}
```

Comment: change `price` to be not static

Comment: [What is the exact meaning of static fields in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/797964/what-is-the-exact-meaning-of-static-fields-in-java)

Comment: Why did you make the field `price` and the method `returnPrice` to be **`static`** ? That's the problem, you shouldn't :- but why did you do it in the first place?

Answer (score 2):

If you need the value of `price` as unique to object, you should not declare it as `static`. If you declare as `static`, it will be accessible within all objects of given class and it won't belong to object.