# Code smell sonarLint - Assigning a value to a static field

Tags: java, spring-boot

can you change that to satisfy sonarLint? if I do not do the assignment the value of my variable is null ...

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class BwsApplication {
    private static ConfigClass config;

    public BwsApplication(ConfigClass configClass) {
        config = configClass;//SONAR - Remove this assignment of "config"
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
        SpringApplication.run(BwsApplication.class, args);
        Connection con = config.getConnection();
        int number = StudentsManager.getStudentsNumber(con);
        QuartzApp qa = new QuartzApp(config);
        qa.excecution(number );
    }
}
```

"Static fields should not be updated in constructors" 
I need to use the variable in a static context!

Comment: Instead of making the assignment in the constructor, you could declare a `public static void init(ConfigClass configClass) { config = configClass; }`. If you know that only a single instance of `BwsApplication` will exist, make it a [Singleton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern).

Comment: how does this make any sense? do you understand why updating a static field in a constructor makes no sense? what do you mean, you need to use the variable in a static context, and why do you need to change it for each instance (also: should existing instances get the same value as the one passed to the new instance))?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The class is annotated with `@SpringBootApplication`.
And for the record, the following is the constructor that is called by Spring Boot during the creation of the bean application :

```
public BwsApplication(ConfigClass configClass) {
    config = configClass;//SONAR - Remove this assignment of "config"
}
```

The SpringBootApplication represented by this class will be instantiated one and only one time. So from a logical point of view, it seems not invalid to make this field a `static` field. But in the facts, making it `static` or no doesn't matter as it will be shared with no more than one instance.  You spare nothing by making it `static`.
I think you made the field `static` because you would use it in the `static` main method.
But it is the not the way to do that.
Instead, remove the `static` modifier and move this code in a instance `@PostConstruct` method that will be executed after the dependency injection was performed on this bean :

```
Connection con = config.getConnection();
int number = StudentsManager.getStudentsNumber(con);
QuartzApp qa = new QuartzApp(config);
qa.excecution(number );
```

In this way, you could refer the `config` field even it is an instance field.

It could look like :

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class BwsApplication {

    private  ConfigClass config;

    public BwsApplication(ConfigClass configClass) {
        config = configClass;//SONAR - Remove this assignment of "config"
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
        SpringApplication.run(BwsApplication.class, args);       
    }

    @PostConstruct
    private void postConstruct() {
      Connection con = config.getConnection();
      int number = StudentsManager.getStudentsNumber(con);
      QuartzApp qa = new QuartzApp(config);
      qa.excecution(number);
    }
}
```

Comment: @Manzini  Great if the explanation was valuable for you :-)

Answer (score 1):

This code looks odd and SonarLint is right to report a code smell. Your field `config` is declared as [`static`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/797964/what-is-the-exact-meaning-of-static-fields-in-java), i.e. it is shared by all instances of `BwsApplication`. Demanding a new `ConfigClass` instance by each constructor call and overriding the `static` fields is most probably not what you want.

You can fix this by making the assignment in some static method, e.g.:

```
public class BwsApplication {
  private static ConfigClass config;
  ...
  public static final void init(final ConfigClass configClass) {
    config = configClass;
  }
}
```

Your constructor will no longer need an argument of type `ConfigClass`.

---

If you can determine the instance of `config` at compile-time, you can deply [JohnSnowDoesNotKnowNothing's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51101390/4216641) and deploy a static initializer block.

---

Just to rule out the possibility: Please make sure you did not confuse [`static`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/797964/what-is-the-exact-meaning-of-static-fields-in-java) with [`final`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15655012/how-does-the-final-keyword-in-java-work-i-can-still-modify-an-object).

Comment: In general yes but it is a spring boot application class.  The `static` modifier was  a workaround to interact with the field in the `main()` method. You can refer to my answer to understand.